# Add custom @types of js libraries that don't have it yet

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Some of the libraries we need to use don't have a `@types` definition yet.

How can custom @types be created and referenced in the `tsconfig.json` to be able to compile components that reference these libraries?

If I create a custom.d.ts file defining the interfaces we need and list the file in the `tsconfig.json` files section would be enough?

Answer (score 1):

To create a new declaration you need to make sure you follow the best practices explained in the **Declaration Files** section in TypeScript handbook [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html).

For consumming the declaration in your project you have two options:

- through "**includes**" or "**files**" in your tsconfig.
- through a `/// <reference path="" />` declaration in your code.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I ended up creating a "@types" folder where I put all the TypeScript Declaration File in separate folders that later it's copied into node_modules/@types using cpx

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing.

For the jquery.spackline plugging...

1. Create Scripts/@types/jquery-sparkline/index.d.ts
2. index.d.ts constructor is defined as simple as possible

   interface JQuery {
       /**
       * By default, options should be passed in as the second argument to the sparkline function
       *
       * @param values of numbers or null values
       * @param options
       */
       sparkline(values: any, options: any): JQuery;

   ```
   /**
   * If values is undefined or set to 'html' then the data values are read from the specified tag:
   * <p>Sparkline: <span class="sparkline">1,4,6,6,8,5,3,5</span></p>
   */
   sparkline(): JQuery;

   /**
    * Otherwise values must be an array of numbers or null values
    *
    * @param values of numbers or null values
    */
   sparkline(values: any): JQuery;
   ```

   }
3. Package.json

   "scripts": {
       "postinstall": "cpx \"Scripts/@types/**/*\" node_modules/@types",
       "tsc": "tsc",
       "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
     },
   ....
   ...
   "devDependencies": {
       "typescript": "^2.0.6",
       "cpx": "~1.5.0"
     }

So, in the Scripts/@types I put all the TypeScript Declaration Files in different folders (one per library). 
Note in the Package.json configuration:

- scripts -> "postinstall": "cpx \"Scripts/@types/**/*\" node_modules/@types",
- devDependencies -> "cpx": "~1.5.0"

All of this might not be required if the TypeScript Declaration Files were posted by the creators of the libraries... I think.